# Unable to view Flamegraph in JDK mission control v8.2

Tags: profiling, jmc

I am using JDK Mission Control v8.2 for profiling a JAVA program for learning purposes. When I go to Threads/Methods and try to find the flame graph of it, the tab is blank.[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w7Xy.png). Also, the Graphview and Heapmap View are not showing any information.

JMC: https://adoptium.net/jmc/ version 8.2
OS: Windows 11

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is currently a problem showing the Flame Graph on Windows (really, any view using JavaScript for visualization). It's related to Eclipse still using InternetExplorer for the embedded browser component.

You can try adding the following system property to the jmc.ini file:
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=edge

That should make the Flame Graph work, but may cause other problems.

Comment: Thank you. For the time being, I will use some other tool for the flame graph.

Comment: Another variant is to use observable and the new Websocket for selections. See the 8.2.0 release notes:
http://hirt.se/blog/?p=1396

See: https://observablehq.com/collection/@cimi/java-mission-control